# all Ipads Devices same Layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, responsive

I started out with using one CLM Platform where we create htmls and upload them to platforms / IOS App,
We go with IPAD size(1024 x 768) only landscape with absolute positioning.

Now I want this to work in all Ipads like Pro, Air, and Mini.  I know I can use media quires but for all the devices it will difficult for me as I have absolute positioning. Is there any way in CSS to use VW or percentage so from now if I create a project it should fit in all.

Comment: are they all the same aspect ratio?

Comment: No but there is a minor difference, its between 1.3 to 1.43165467626

Comment: Probabily you should use bootstrap or any other library for responsiveness. It becomes very easy with them. Even by just importing the library to your project (either by downloading manually or by CDN) it makes the viewport responsive.

Comment: Bootstrap has overhead.  If you have the time and patience, and can call the shots on a few UI ideas, code it yourself with CSS media.